# Uniform convergence of $f_n(z)=nz^n$ in the set $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

In an exercise I have to prove that $f_n(z)=nz^n$ converges uniformly for $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$.

So I have to prove that:

$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}:|nz^n-f(z)|<\varepsilon\ \ \ \text{if } n\geq N$$

My question is, how can I find that $f(z)$?

I've tried calculating the $\lim_n nz^n$ but I got stuck. How can I evaluate this limit?

Comment: For a given $z$ with $|z|<1$, we have $nz^n \to 0$. So, $f(z) = 0$ for all $|z| < 1/2.$ Next step is to prove that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: yes sure, but $\infty \times 0$ is an indeterminate form

Comment: Hm, I agree, but where are you getting that from?

Comment: Yes but isn't that just to prove that it converges? I want to find the exact limit @TitoEliatron

Comment: $nz^n\to 0$: just change $n$ to $x$ and use L'Hopital, for instance.

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman we have $nz^n$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $z^n \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Eduude Yep, I agree that $n \to +\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, and also that $z^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. However, I do not agree that these two facts imply $n z^n \to (+\infty) \cdot 0$ (which, as you correctly pointed out, is indeterminate). That would be an incorrect application of limit laws, which generally hold for *convergent* sequences, which the identity sequence $n$ is not. You would want to prove as a lemma that $nz^n \to 0$, which is done using an $\varepsilon$-argument.

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman I'd say that's a bit too pedantic. "Implying" $(+\infty)\cdot0$ simply says "suppose I try and break it into two limits and multiply, then I end up with an indeterminate form". The conclusion is "therefore I can't simply break it up".

Comment: Ah, sorry, not trying to be pedantic, that's simply the way I think about it. That's just my intuition for the fact that, like you say "I can't simply break it up."

Comment: I see this is tagged for complex analysis. BTW if it is known that $na^n \to 0$ for real $a$ with $|a|<1$, then the result for complex $z$ follows because $|nz^n| = n|z|^n := na^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're taking the limit wrt $n$, treat $z$ as a constant. To make things easier while taking powers, consider the polar form:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nz^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\underbrace{\left|z\right|^n}_{\leq\frac{1}{2^n}}e^{in\arg(z)}$$

So clearly the magnitude of the terms just goes to zero. There's only one complex number with magnitude zero.

Answer (score 1):

Observation: The point-wise limit is zero as discussed in the comments. [edit: Strictly speaking, we don't need to know this in order to prove that the uniform limit is zero, but it's kind of a helpful clue.]

Now, we will show that there exists a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ converging to zero such that $|a_n| \geq |f_n(z)| = |f_n(z)-f(z)|$ for all $n$ and all $|z|<1/2$. It is $a_n := n2^{-n}$ $(n \geq 1)$. Thus, for a given $\varepsilon>0$, for some $N$, we have $\varepsilon > |a_n|$ for all $n \geq N$. So, $\varepsilon > |a_n| \geq |f_n(z)-f(z)|$ for all $|z|<1/2$ and all $n \geq N$. In particular, $\varepsilon > |f_n(z)-f(z)|$ for all $|z|<1/2$ and all $n \geq N$. QE-deedly-D